# Google Drive SDK Python Quickstart Sample

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I see this tutorial and try to run the test code
Google Drive SDK Python Quickstart Sample

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJVCKvXtHtE&list=PL0FA2818902D9D123

Code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GD3Ee07QsqxQZ-UDTNIbMqtSu4U_servCeQsd9rCkp8/edit

I got an error, it is saying "ValueError: The value of redirect_uri must not be None"

I googled, can't fix this problem.
What should I fix?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is really simple actually.The api just needs to know what to do with the credential.You see a installed application and a web application handles it differently.For a web application, authorising would redirect the user to another page. For a installed application, you might want to be provided with a key.

So if you are using a installed application, change the following lines of code.

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

path_to_json="client_secrets.json"    # download from https://code.google.com/apis/console/
AUTH_SCOPE 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#redirect_uri also provided in api console.The other URI mentioned there is for web applications.

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(Path_to_JSON,AUTH_SCOPE,redirect_uri="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was add **redirect_uri="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"** in the code.

```
#Before

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE)

#After

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, redirect_uri="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
```